# Dynamic object parameter in camel consumer endpoint url

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm using camel with spring.
One of our routes should send a TCP message to a dynamically selected endpoint.
As the endpoint is just a string, I know I can use

```
.toD("netty4://...")
```

but the problem is with setting ssl parameters.

Netty component defines this as route url parameter so it looks like this:

```
.toD("netty4://...?sslContextParameters=mySslContextParameters");
```

and to make this work I have a bean:

```
@Bean
public SslContextParameters mySslContextParameters() {
    ...
    return sslContextParameters();
}
```

This binds it to this single bean instance but what I need, is a dynamically configured bean so that I may set different parameters of the SSL based on some data I get from the producer.

What I would like is something like this (I know this is not proper camel syntax), when I could invoke a factory method and pass some parameters to it:

```
.toD("netty://...?sslContextParameters=${bean('mySslContestParameters(${exchange.param1}, ${exchange.param2}')}");
```

Comment: Have you looked into bean binding? https://camel.apache.org/bean.html

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use bean binding so I would be able to pass parameters that bean factory method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recipient list EIP per this [camel FAQ](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html).

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the recipient list EIP per this camel FAQ.

Thx Steve, it was a good advice.

I had a similiar question, I used your advice and it's work!

In my camel-context.xml, I define two sslContextParameters

```
...
<camel:sslContextParameters id="firstSsl">
    <camel:keyManagers keyPassword="changeit">
        <camel:keyStore resource="/test/client.keystore.jks" password="changeit" />
    </camel:keyManagers>
    <camel:trustManagers>
            <camel:keyStore resource="/test/client.truststore.jks" password="changeit" />
    </camel:trustManagers>
</camel:sslContextParameters>
<camel:sslContextParameters id="secondSsl">
    <camel:keyManagers keyPassword="otherpassword">
        <camel:keyStore resource="/test/other-keystore.jks" password="otherpassword" />
    </camel:keyManagers>
    <camel:trustManagers>
        <camel:keyStore resource="/test/other-truststore.jks" password="otherpassword" />
    </camel:trustManagers>
</camel:sslContextParameters>
...
```

In my routeBuilder

```
.setHeader("sslContext", constant("firstSsl"))
//or
.setHeader("sslContext", constant("secondSsl"))
...
.recipientList(simple("https4://override/?bridgeEndpoint=false&sslContextParametersRef=${headers.sslContext}"))
```